# How to prove by symmetry that tension in a section of rapidly rotating wheel act tangentially?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, symmetry, centripetal-force

Suppose a thin uniform wheel of radius $r$ is rotating rapidly about its axis; its spokes have almost negligible strength.

According to the book, the centripetal force is provided by the tension acting tangentially on a infinitesimal cross-section. The argument is:

> . . .it is clear that the forces acting on the small portion must be supplied via its contact with adjacent material of the rim. This forces must, by **symmetry** be tangential to the rim at each point.

My question is:

What is meant by **symmetry** here and how does it prove that the tension from the adjacent material act tangentially?

Comment: This is basically the same question why a lasso  expands into a circular loop. The book isn't written very well since the author can't seem to live without  unnecessary elements like "negligible spokes". The symmetry argument is, all by itself, nonsensical. Such a structure is capable of very nasty higher order excitations where the forces would not be acting tangentially, moreover, there is a phase transition at high enough angular velocity where the circular configuration will become unstable and a practical structure like that will tear itself apart. The complete analysis is very complex.

Comment: Hi @CuriousOne, can you tell me what symmetry means here?

Comment: Symmetry means the circular symmetry of the most simple solution to the rotating hoop problem. Unfortunately for you and the authors of this book, the actual problem doesn't have the same symmetry as its most simple solution and they are not spelling that out clearly (probably because they don't want to confuse you). The symmetry is not natural and such a system will not always take on such a symmetry (you could ask the engineers of rotating machine parts how hard it is to enforce that rotating things stay round!). For your purpose, simply assume that the ring always stays symmetric.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Thanks, sir for describing all the real circumstance. However, can you please tell how the symmetry proves that tension acts tangentially?